# Install mpeg4ip using apt on Ubuntu 14.04TLS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, mpeg-4

I want to install mpeg4ip tool on ubuntu14.04TLS. I have searched and found below answer:

```
sudo apt-get install mpeg4ip-server
```

But it seems doesn't work.

Then I found [mpeg4ip 1:1.6dfsg-0.2ubuntu8 source package in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mpeg4ip/1:1.6dfsg-0.2ubuntu8) but I don't know how to use it as upstream.

I can see the tar package but I don't think I have to build it myself. I guess many dependency so it's better to install binary.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Just got below solution:

First,Add source of lucid.

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
add below lines to this file
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
```

Second, Run update command to update software list

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Then, Run command to install mpeg4ip tool.

```
$sudo apt-get install mpeg4ip-utils
$sudo apt-get install mpeg4ip-server
$sudo apt-get install gpac # Install MP4Box tool
```

Done.