# Build mpeg4ip library on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to build mpeg4ip library for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The command `make && make install` throws error as below. I referred to [Install mpeg4ip using apt on Ubuntu 14.04TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29553548/608639) but it shows 404 while updating.

```
make[4]: *** [rtphint.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mpeg4ip-1.5.0.1/lib/mp4v2'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mpeg4ip-1.5.0.1/lib/mp4v2'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mpeg4ip-1.5.0.1/lib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mpeg4ip-1.5.0.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I install this library in my linux machine.

Comment: Hi. You need to show a few of the lines in your `make` output before those lines - before it starts saying "Leaving directory".

Comment: Full log as [link](https://pastebin.com/index/VtKx1xsd)

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong because so much information is missing. Try `./configure && make && sudo make install`

Comment: You should ask on askubuntu rather than here

Comment: The error message is `invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]`. Looks like the project doesn't strictly follow types properties, and modern compiler with default settings emits error about that. You may add compiler option `-fpermissive` for tell a compiler to ignore such problems. About adding compiler flags for `configure` see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407635/append-compile-flags-to-cflags-and-cxxflags-while-configuration-make).

Comment: configure: error: unrecognized option: -fpermissive